# Can't set max height on child div properly

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I have following layout:

[image]

Here is the code:

```
<div style={{ height: "100%", display: "flex", flexDirection: "column" }}>
  <div style={{ height: 300 }}>test</div>
  <div style={{ flex: 1, display: "flex", border: "1px solid green" }} >
    <div style={{ flex: 1, maxHeight: 350, overflow: "auto", border: "3px solid red" }}>
      <ResultsTable />
    </div>
    <div style={{ flex: 1, }}></div>
  </div>
</div >
```

You can see setting `maxHeight: 350` worked above and there is a `scrollbar`, but the height of the red `div` is smaller than height of the green `div`, ideally I think one would like to have the height of the red `div` same as height of green `div`, and then to have a vertical scrollbar too. How can I achieve this in such setup?

**Note:** <s>having `maxHeight: 100%` on the red `div`, didn't work, as both red and green `div` just increased in height.</s>

**Question seems to be resolved**: There was issue in above Note, actually `maxHeight:100%`, does seem to work on red div: http://codesandbox.io/s/inspiring-lederberg-ni52j, it wasn't working in my project because the parent of top div from this example had `flex:1` (that parent isn't seen here) .

Comment: Could you provide a replaceable example? Without working with the rendered code it's difficult to guess at which other properties could be conflicting. i.e you could just have a margin bottom on your red border and we'd never know.

Comment: @AlexanderDeSousa Do you mean a demo? https://codesandbox.io/s/ecstatic-sun-0e4yl

Comment: To clarify, do you want the red box to become bigger to fit the green box, or do you want to green box to collapse down to fit the red box?

Comment: @AlexanderDeSousa red to become bigger and fit green

Comment: use `!important` after your style so that it doesn't get overwritten by anything else.

Comment: The `maxHeight: 100%` from your note would work exactly as you want then, I can't see it increasing the height of the green div.

Comment: Or maybe you do actually want to collapse the green div but not phrased the question well? Does this look like what you want: https://codesandbox.io/s/admiring-mendeleev-9hqd3

Comment: I may have confused some people here, actually maxHeight:100% does seem to work on red div: https://codesandbox.io/s/inspiring-lederberg-ni52j, it wasn't working in my project, because the parent of top div from this example had `flex:1` (that parent isn't seen here)

Comment: Perfect, that's why it's important to have the code to work with.

Answer (score 2):

Try to use `height: "auto"` and `maxHeight: "100%"` in the red div.

Here is the [updated style](https://codesandbox.io/s/hardcore-yonath-c6euz).